# Finding a path in a graph in prolog

Tags: prolog

Let's assume I have facts in Prolog as follows:

```
path(a,b).  
path(a,c).
```

and I want to code the the function `ispath(X,Y)` which returns true if there is a path from `X` to `Y` in one or more steps. It fails if `X=Y`. Assume
an acyclic graph.

Solution

```
isPath(X,Y) :- arrow(X,Y).  
isPath(X,Y) :- arrow(X,R), arrow(R,Y).
```

My question is if prolog returns some element for R in the first call of arrow and there is no path from R to y in the second call, does prolog return false? or keep searching for all the possible paths until one is found.

Comment: Not it will not stop, it will move back to `àrrow(X,R)` and try to find a value for `R` such that `X` and `R` are connected and for that value of `R` it will try to find a `Y`

Comment: Actually, it will backtrack to `arrow(X, R)` and look for any valid instantiation of `X` or `R` to cause that call to succeed. It won't just vary `R`. By the way, `X` is singleton in this *predicate* (Prolog does not have *functions*) so serves no purpose as a named variable. Also, variables cannot start with a lower case letter. So `isPath(x,y)` and `arrow(R,y)` appear to by typographical errors.

Comment: @lurker sorry. Typo fixed.